# Not able to write into the file from a process but was able to access the file object using Multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have used multiprocessing module and created a process, in which I want to access a file and need to write some logs in  it.
I have specific dependency,that's why i have declared file outside worker function, and from worked function i am able to print and access the file object but was not able to write anything to it.

could  you please suggest how can i write to that file.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

file1 = open("files.txt",'w+')

def worker():
    print "iam called"
    print file1
    file1.write("hello 123")


jobs = []
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
jobs.append(p)
p.start()
time.sleep(10)
p.terminate()
```

output:

```
iam called
<open file 'files.txt', mode 'w+' at 0x7f5ee8bd7f60>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the file once you put some data into it. Do:

```
file1.write("hello 123")
file1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to open your files using `with`, which will explicitly close the file after you have worked on it;

```
with open('files.txt', 'w+') as file1:
    #Perform actions here
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are exactly trying to achieve here. 
As per your code, file1 will be a FileStream object. You are sharing this single stream within multiple address spaces of your process. Thats the first flaw.

When your function tries executing the multi processed function, the file stream does not get shared. Moreover, the reference to file1 FileStream is NOT destroyed and hence you are able to access the file but not write to it.
Also, why are you opening in 'w+' mode ? Is there any explicit reason for you to truncate the file?

To solve it, you should open the file stream within the function executing spawning the processes:

```
def worker():
    print "iam called"
    with open(files.txt",'w+'):
        file1.write("hello 123")
```